# How to Implement Role Based Authorization in MVC3 with Fluent NHibernate?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, fluent-nhibernate

Our MVC3 application is using Fluent NHibernate and requires implementation of user login, authentication and authorization.

I've seen articles using the `[Authorize]` method in the controller classes.  However, I'm not sure how this all works in our situation given that Fluent NHibernate is in use.

Can anyone share some suggestions as to how to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could [write a custom role provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8fw7xh74.aspx) implementing the [RoleProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.aspx) class. In your custom implementation you of the RoleProvider class you could use whatever database access technology you want - FluentNhibernate or whatever. Basically you are interested in implementing the [IsUserInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.isuserinrole.aspx) method.

Then decorate your controllers/actions with the Authorize attribute:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin")]
public ActionResult Foo()
{
    return Content("Only administrators can see this message");
}
```

And here's another [`blog post`](http://kitsula.com/Article/Custom-Role-Provider-for-MVC) that covers writing a custom role provider in more details.